# fread does not insert a value

Tags: c

i am getting a really weird problam when i am trying to start the program.
the `## fread ##`fuction does not insert to the vairabel (cu) a value. (line 7)
does somebody knows why? or how i can solve it?
the function `## marge ##` gets two binary files that we know has numbers in increasing order and in the other file there are numbers in decreasing order. 
and it supposed to Combine them into one file in a increasing order.(i am not allowed to use any arrays or other data structure).
thank you very much:)
here is the code:
(it in c language)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define _NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
void marge(FILE* a, FILE* b) {
    FILE* res = fopen("C:\\Users\\shachar\\Desktop\\f.txt", "w+");
    int cu=0, cd=0, inx=1;
    fread(&cu,sizeof(int), 1, a);  // the problem is here!!
    fseek(b, 0, SEEK_END);         //cu stays 0
    fread(&cd, 4, 1, b);
    while (ftell(a)!=-1||ftell(b)){
        if (cu > cd) {
            fprintf(res, "%d ", cu);
            fread(&cu, 4, 1, a);
        }
        else {
            fprintf(res, "%d ", cu);
            fseek(b, SEEK_END, -inx);
            inx++;
            fread(&cd, 4, 1, b);
        }
    }
    while (ftell(a) != -1) {
        fprintf(res, "%d ", cu);
        fread(&cu, 4, 1, a);
    }
    while (ftell(b)){
        fprintf(res, "%d ", cu);
        fseek(b, SEEK_END, -inx);
        inx++;
        fread(&cd, 4, 1, b);
    }
    _fcloseall();
}

int main(void) {
    FILE* a = fopen("C:\\Users\\shachar\\Desktop\\x.txt", "r+" );
    FILE* b = fopen("C:\\Users\\shachar\\Desktop\\y.txt", "r+");
    marge(a, b);

}`
```

Comment: Here's a thought. Rather than ignoring the result of your `fread` calls, perhaps check them and see what `perror()` reports if they fail. Fyi, the "destroy contents" mention in [the documentation for `fopen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) when opened with `w+` may prove informative.

Comment: And check what happens when you open the files too, every time, to prevent using `NULL` pointers.

Comment: You say you are "not allowed" to use various language features, but funnily enough you are allowed to disable compiler warnings. What happens when you remove that line `#pragma warning(disable:4996)`? On top of my earlier comment you are not checking the return values from others functions which are provided for your benefit to ensure the code is not stumbling. Such as `fread` and `fseek`.

Comment: What do you intend to happen here? `fseek(b, 0, SEEK_END); fread(&cd, 4, 1, b);`

Comment: i tried to read the last number. @weather vane

Comment: That is *beyond* the last number. It's the end of the file. If you want to read the last (binary, not text) number, `fseek(b, -sizeof cd, SEEK_END)`

Answer (score 4):

You aren't opening the files correctly. If you want to read from existing files, the last argument in your fopen should be 'r' not 'w'.

Comment: a and b are opened in main() below marge().

Comment: Mea Culpa - removed the comment :( - and upvoted your answer :)

Comment: thank you:) but it didnt soved the problem, its still doesnt enter a value:(  do you have any idea why?

Comment: Are there values in the files? If you ran the code you had before, the files would have been overwritten with empty files.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you only want to **read** from filestream `a`, so open it like so:

```
FILE* a = fopen("C:\\Users\\shachar\\Desktop\\x.txt", "r+" );
```

With `w+` the file is truncated.

A similar problem may exist with `b`

Comment: `"r+`" is for both reading and writing, `"r"` is for reading.

Comment: Yes I understand that. It felt to me, though, that OP wanted read/write ability with the file, and approached it with `w+` instead of `r+`, but did not realize the behavior was so different.

Comment: thank you:) but it didnt soved the problem, its still doesnt enter a value:(  do you have any idea why?

Comment: oh you are right but now its inserting a very large number and not the first one. any idea?

Comment: @s.laufer: Sounds like a data issue. You may have whitespace characters like `' '` and `'\n'`. Do you really want to be using `fread`? Perhaps you want `fscanf`? `fread` is reading bytes and will not skip spaces, whereas `fscanf` will skip whitespace characters.

Comment: but i cant use fscanf on binary file. or do i?

Comment: @s.laufer: That's correct. It's for formatted input. I guess I'd suggest you look at a hex dump of your file to make sure it looks like you think it should.

Comment: so what do i do to fix it?

Comment: @s.laufer: Did you examine your data with some other tool to make sure it was all correct? It sounds like you are indeed reading bytes now, just not what you expected.